# Why in HTML and JavaScript, if the content is being scrolled up and down, the content does not get a scroll event?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I think sometimes it can be confusing for a `scroll` event, that, say if window is 800 x 300 pixel, and the content (the `body` element) is 800 x 2000, and the body is scrolled up and down, the `body` does not get a `scroll` event, but the `window` does.

Similarly, if div A contains div B, and div B is too big to fit in div A and div B is being scrolled up and down, div B does not get a `scroll` event but div A does.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/RL5Qj/

So it is a bit confusing at times, and can we think of the `scroll` event more as a `contentscrolled` event?

(or is the phrase "div B is being scrolled up and down" not technically correct, but that it should be "div A is scrolled up and down to show part of div B"?  But I hear the phrase "the content is being scrolled up and down (inside the window)" all the time.)

Comment: Create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> is the phrase "div B is being scrolled up and down" not technically
>   correct

Yes, that phrase is wrong, because in your case div A is being scrolled (this div has scrollbars). Even better is to say that the content canvas of div A is being scrolled and it doesn't matter what is placed on that canvas.

It's like humans (div B) on the Earth (div A). The planet is moving/rotating like crazy but nobody feels that (no event received). :)

Comment: interesting analogy with the earth... if "scroll" has a similar meaning with "move" or "shift", then it should be div B (the content) that is moved or shifted, rather than div A (the container).

Comment: No, the content is not **moved** but ... **carried**. :)

Comment: you can very well say the content was inside a div with overflow: hidden and then itself is just position: absolute with a top and left adjusted, so that's moved, and it is the same as the scrolled effect.

Comment: Agree, but with `overflow:hidden` on div A and `position:absolute` on div B you will not have scrollbars and scroll event. Of course you can simulate scrollbars on div A and trigger scroll event while dragging div B, but this is not what you have asked in the original question. ;)